# R: Producing word cloud using Spanish text

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

Here is my code. 
I need to text mine this into a word cloud. Is there a way to get this code with the Spanish letters and symbols and such or is there a way after I am all finished to have the word cloud include it.

```
> textsp=readLines("Reflection- Spanish .txt",encoding = "latin-1")
 > textsp
 [1] "Para ti"                         
 [2] "Lo que ves de m\x92"             
 [3] "Es la realidad"                  
 [4] "Mas t\x9c no conoces"            
 [5] "El papel, que la vida"           
 [6] "Me hace actuar"                  
 [7] "Siendo as\x92"                   
 [8] "Yo puedo burlar"                 
 [9] "Mi mundo exterior"               
[10] "Pero al coraz\x97n"              
[11] "Jam\x87s"                        
[12] "Hoy no reconoc\x92"              
[13] "A quien vi, frente a m\x92"      
[14] "Mi reflejo no mostr\x97"         
[15] "Quien soy en verdad"             
[16] "Un d\x92a m\x87s"                
[17] "Que mi coraz\x97n"               
[18] "Tengo que ocultar"               
[19] "Todo mi sentir"                  
[20] "Al final"                        
[21] "Sabr\x87n como soy"              
[22] "Que pienso en verdad"            
[23] "Ese d\x92a llegar\x87"           
[24] "Hoy no reconoc\x92"              
[25] "A quien vi, frente a m\x92"      
[26] "Esa en mi reflejo"               
[27] "S\x8e que no soy yo"             
[28] "No quiero aparentar"             
[29] "Quiero ser realidad"             
[30] "Mi reflejo no mostr\x97"         
[31] "Quien soy en verdad"             
[32] "Y en mi coraz\x97n sentir, volar"
[33] "No soy, como quiero no"          
[34] "Y voy a cambiar"                 
[35] "No debe ser as\x92"              
[36] "El fingir, no es vivir"          
[37] "La que veo frente a m\x92"       
[38] "No aguanta m\x87s"               
[39] "Ya no voy a ocultar"             
[40] "La que soy"                      
[41] "Nunca m\x87s"                    
[42] "Un buen d\x92a"                  
[43] "El amor"                         
[44] "Me rescatar\x87"                 
[45] "Y ese d\x92a"                    
[46] "Quien yo soy"                    
[47] "Se reflejar\x87..."
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's `latin-1`? Try `UTF-8`. What's the actual plain text?

Comment: Yo puedo burlar
Mi mundo exterior
Pero al corazón
Jamás
Hoy no reconocí
A quien vi, frente a mí
Mi reflejo no mostró
Quien soy en verdad This is a portion of the txt. file. I tried UTF-8 as well.

Comment: I just tried the line with the exact same code you provided and it rendered correctly. It must be something with your system. What version of R? Are you using Rstudio if so what version? I'm going to guess your RStudio is < 0.93 and needs to update.   What you're seeing here is probably older version of RStudio not rendered non-ASCII characters correctly.